# plain text code parameters VS environment variables for web applications?

Tags: django, parameters, django-settings

When we define settings for web applications, we face the choice to use plain text information on code or to request environment variable. Examples : (Stripe_KEY, Database name, Database password, ALLOWED_HOSTS for CORS, etc.)

Concrete example on django : 
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '*')]` VS `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost:8000']`

Comment: Environment variables is good.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Why ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786138/2282638